# Dealing with characteristics of First-Order Wave Equation with initial condition of $w(0,t)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

> Solve $$({\partial w}/{\partial t})+4{\partial w}/{\partial x}=0$$
>   with $w(0,t)=\sin(3t)$.

I know how to do this with $t=0$ and just $x$ but how do you approach this?
I know that $x=4t+x_0$ but I get stumped as you have $f(t)$ not $f(x)$.

Comment: This is a *transport equation*, not a wave equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already found that $w$ is constant on every line of the form $x-4t=C$, for any constant $C$. Therefore, $w$ can be written as $g(x-4t)$ where $g$ is some function to be determined. (Why? Because this form says precisely that as soon as we know which characteristic line the point $(x,t)$ is on, we know $w$.)

It remains to plug in the given condition: when $x=0$, $w=\sin 3t$. So,
$$g(-4t)=\sin 3t$$
I'll leave for you to write down the formula for $g$, and formulate the answer $w(x,t)=g(x-4t)$.

Comment: But how do I write the formula for g is it just solving for t and plugging it into g(x-4t)? Usually we'd be able to just solve for x_$0$ and plug in but this is what I don't get from here.

Comment: Let's introduce one more letter: put $z=-4t$. Then $t=-z/4$. So, $g(z) = \sin (-3z/4)$. Hm, does not this look like a formula for $g$?